# Arabic on storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard, arabic

I want to localize my application, it work fine when I set english and french language on the device but when I try with arabic I have the english storyboard :/

When I have create the file "Localizable" for the arabic language I choose "Arabic-World" I try with others like "Arabic-Algeria" but I have the same results.

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: which Xcode version are you using and how did you originally add your new localization to your project?

Comment: I use xcode 4.5, I have add the localization on "Localization" section in the "Info" of my project

Comment: Have you localized `InfoPlist.strings` for Arabic-World?  In my testing, an app must have a localization of `InfoPlist.strings` for each locale it wants to support.

Comment: Yes For each locale I have infoPlist.string, storyboard and Localizable.string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it By removing Arabic-World localization and then localize my app with "Arabic" (I didn't see it when when I choosed the language)